# osx disable osx upgrade

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I've stated installation of osx el capitan. After reboot I'm stuck on "there's no enough space to install osx el capitan" (I have 8GB free). After each restart there is the same procedure. Is there way how to disable the installation process and return back to yosemite to decide which files I can backup and which I can delete?

Thanks

Comment: not easily. Your choices are boot to recovery & do it from terminal, or if you're not happy in terminal start the machine in Target Disk Mode & work from another Mac. btw, 8GB of free space is suicidally low, minimum 15% of an HD or 20% of an SSD is recommended.

Comment: How to do it from terminal? I didn't started that update unfortunately (user does) and it's shame that osx does allow this to user.

Comment: from terminal you'd have to manually navigate around, copy large files off to another location or delete. Too complex to even start to put that in an answer.